# adding newly create topic to subscription in reactive kafka

Tags: akka, reactive-kafka

iam developing reactive kafka in our  play scala project,  in the project we created 5 topic which are  subscribed by consumer group and working good, now the problem is  i created a new topic, how can i add this topic to the existing consumer group ( is it possible)
 my code is :

```
val consumerSettings = ConsumerSettings(system, new ByteArrayDeserializer, new StringDeserializer)
      .withBootstrapServers(bootStrapServer)
      .withGroupId(groupId).withPollInterval(100 millis)

   Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(topicList))
            .groupedWithin(10, 15 seconds)
            .map({
              group =>
                var offSetBatch = CommittableOffsetBatch.empty
                val sessionList = group.toList.map { eachItem =>
                  offSetBatch = offSetBatch.updated(eachItem.committableOffset)
                  Json.parse(eachItem.record.value()).as[cityModel]
                }
                processRecords(cityList)
                offSetBatch
            }).mapAsync(1)(_.commitScaladsl())
            .toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.both)
            .run()
```

is there any way that i can add topic to consumer

Answer (score 0):

While creating a consumer, we can give topic a pattern as

`Subscriptions.topicPattern("*.in")`  this should will solve problem